`foreach` does not work together with `ifthenelse` and `mod`
In the minimal example below, the commented out line does not work.
Other lines work correctly.
I can't understand what the reason is.
Here is a similar question, but my variable \im takes integer values.
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}    
    \def\m{12}
    \def\n{13}    
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\m}{\coordinate[label=] (u\i) at (360*\i/\n:1);}
     
     \foreach \i in { 0,...,\m}{%        
         \pgfmathMod{\i}{5}\edef\im{\pgfmathresult}        
         \draw[blue] (u\im) circle (0.04);               
         \ifthenelse{\i =0}{ }{\draw[red,fill] (u\i) circle (0.02);}
         %\ifthenelse{\im=0}{ }{\draw[green,fill] (u\i) circle (0.01);}
     }
 
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}


\im is a float, you can convert it to int with \pgfmathMod{\i}{5}\pgfmathint{\pgfmathresult}

If you add \show\im after the \edef, you'll see at the first cycle
> \im=macro:
->0.0.

and
> \im=macro:
->1.0.

at the second cycle. This cannot work with \ifthenelse, that expects integers.
Use \pgmathtruncatemacro{\im}{mod(\i,5)} instead.
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\m{12}
  \def\n{13}
  \foreach \i in {0,...,\m}{\coordinate[label=] (u\i) at (360*\i/\n:1);}
  \foreach \i in { 0,...,\m}{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\im}{mod(\i,5)}
    \draw[blue] (u\im) circle (0.04);
    \ifthenelse{\im=0}{}{\draw[green,fill] (u\i) circle (0.01);}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



In general it is strange that the mod function returns a non integer value. But `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\im}{mod(\i,5)}' works  thank you very much.
And here's another thing. Why are the blue circles drawn correctly \draw[blue] (u\im) circle (0.04);?

@kabenyuk The “mod” function can also be used with nonintegers.
